# Refused to set unsafe header when running javascript in Service Cloud

Tags: visualforce, soap-api, service-cloud-console, servicecloud

I'm trying to create a button which will:

1) change case status to resolved
2) reload primary tab in service console or refresh a page in classical UI

BUT I'm getting an error
**Refused to set unsafe header 'User Agent'**
and the field is changed but primary tab isn't refreshed, but after manually reloading a page, I can see the change; in classical UI everything works except firing the same error. (BTW I'm using Chrome, latest version).

How to fix it? Adding a button seems like an easy task.

Here's my code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/support/console/37.0/integration.js')}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js')}

sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';

var c = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
c.id = "{!Case.Id}"; 
c.Status = 'Resolved'; 

result = sforce.connection.update([c]); 

if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) {
    sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(refreshTab);
} else {
    window.location.reload();
}

var refreshTab = function (tab) {
    if (tab.success) {
        sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(tab.id, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried replacing that with sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}'; with sforce.connection.sessionId= '{!$Api.Session_ID}'; ??

Comment: @AlphaBravo you made my day!. Thanks. But I'm completely out of any ideas why it worked. There's no longer a user agent error. And it works in service console. Could you tell why? Any resources to read about `sessionId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sforce.connection.sessionId= '{!$Api.Session_ID}'; will work for you.

My understanding is $API.Session_ID is a global variable that the system will pull when you execute a button.(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_api.htm). When you use GETSESSIONID(), it is a visualforce function that's available on visualforce pages.(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm)